# Get page output with curl --fail

Tags: http, curl, http-post, wget, postfile

Calling curl without parameters, I get the page output, even with an http status code = 404:

```
$ curl http://www.google.com/linux
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/linux</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

$ echo $?
0
```

The status code is 0.

Calling it with `--fail` will not show the output:

```
$ curl --fail http://www.google.com/linux
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

$ echo $?
22
```

The status code is 22 now ...

I'd like to get the output even when http status = 404, 500 (like the first curl execution) and, at the same time, get a different system error (like in the second curl execution, $? = 22).

Is it possible with curl? If not, how could I achieve this with another tool (this tool must accept file uploads and post data! `wget` doesn't seem to be an alternative ...)

Answer (score 41):

This is now possible with curl. Since version 7.76.0 you can do

```
curl --fail-with-body ...
```

Which does exactly what OP asked: shows the document body and exits with code 22.

See https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--fail-with-body

Answer (score 36):

First of all the maximum value for the error code(or exit code) is `255`. Here is the [reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Also, the `--fail` will not allow you to do what you are looking for. However, you can use alternate ways(writing a shell script) to handle the scenario, but not sure it will be effective or not for you!

```
http_code=$(curl -s -o out.html -w '%{http_code}'  http://www.google.com/linux;)

if [[ $http_code -eq 200 ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

## decide which status you want to return for 404 or 500
exit  204
```

Now do the `$?` and you'll get the exit code from there.

You'll find the response html inside the `out.html` file.

You can also pass the url to the script as commandline argument. [Check here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script).

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1641410 has a better implementation with (almost) proper use of temporary files.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately not possible with curl. But you can do this with wget.

```
$ wget --content-on-error -qO- http://httpbin.org/status/418

    -=[ teapot ]=-

       _...._
     .'  _ _ `.
    | ."` ^ `". _,
    \_;`"---"`|//
      |       ;/
      \_     _/
        `"""`
$ echo $?
8
```

Comment: Note that you need wget 1.14+

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @timaschew, here is my enhanced version based on pure awk:

```sh
curl_fail_with_body() {
  curl -o - -w "\n%{http_code}\n" "$@" | awk '{l[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-1; i++) print l[i]}; END{ if ($0<200||$0>299) exit $0 }'
}

# example usage
curl_fail_with_body -sS http://httpbin.org/status/418
```

#### Explanation

- `-o - -w "\n%{http_code}\n"` - prints out to stdout (actually it's piped to the next command) with status code at the end
- `{l[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-1; i++) print l[i]}` - print all the lines except the last one
- `END{ if ($0<200||$0>299) exit $0 }` - will exit with non zero code if the `last line != 2xx`

alternative version, if you want to output the error code after command:
`END{ if ($0<200||$0>299) {print "The requested URL returned error: " $0; exit 1}`

---

BTW, curl supports `--fail-with-body` option since v7.76.0.
This option allows you to achieve the desired behavior without using external tools.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Nit: the exit code range is 0-255, so any HTTP status code > 255 won't come through as exit code. I changed it in my usage to `exit 1` vs. `exit $0`.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution because wget was not suitable for sending multipart/form-data

```
curl -o - -w "\n%{http_code}\n" http://httpbin.org/status/418 | tee >(tail -n 1 | cmp <(echo 2xx) - ) | tee >(grep "char 2"; echo $? > status-code) && grep 0 status-code
```

#### Explanation

`-o - -w "\n%{http_code}\n"` - prints out to stdout (actually it's piped to the next command) with status code at the end
`tee` - output will be piped to next command and additionally printed to stdout
`tail -n 1` - extract status code from the last line
`cmp <(echo 2xx) -` compare status code, first char only
`grep "char 2"` - if first character needs to be 2, otherwise fail

In a shell script you can also do better comparison (currently it only allows 2xx, so redirect like 300 are are handled as an error with `cmp` how it is used above)

Comment: isn't it suppose to not fail when having a 200 response ? cause the previous comment does fail when calling http://httpbin.org/status/200

Comment: What do you exactly mean? The curl command I printed is not failing with 200

Comment: It does fail on my machine. 

Comment: @SeB.Fr is right. It exits with a non-zero code on 2xx status ranges. On a macos at least.

Comment: As well as on GNU bash: https://repl.it/@sepehr/curl-fail-with-error-body

Comment: Required a change from `grep "char 2"` to `grep "byte 2"`. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution - it uses `jq` and assumes the body is json

```sh
#  this code adds a statusCode field to the json it receives and then jq squeezes them together
# curl 7.76.0 will have curl --fail-with-body and thus eliminate all this
  local result
  result=$(
    curl -sL -w ' { "statusCode": %{http_code}} ' -X POST "${headers[@]}" "${endpoint}" \
      -d "${body}"  "$curl_opts" | jq -ren '[inputs] | add'
  )
#   always output the result
  echo "${result}"
#  jq -e will produce an error code if the expression result is false or null - thus resulting in a
# error return code from this function naturally. This is much preferred rather than assume/hardcode
# the existence of a error object in the body payload
  echo "${result}" | jq -re '.statusCode >= 200 and .statusCode < 300' > /dev/null
```